# Linker is unable to tell the difference between function and variables?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Below is my code:

```
//Module 1
void sth()
{
}
```

```
//Module 2

int sth= 1;
int func()
{
}
```

and when invoking `gcc`, the linker throws an error:

> multiple definitions of sth found.

But is the link that dumb that it couldn't tell the difference between functions and variables? Especially there is a symbols table in ELF, there is a "type" in `Elf64_Symbol` to differentiate function and object.  Why doesn't the linker use this information?

Comment: Don't slander the linker. 1) I doubt main can be used as a variable.It appears to me to be a restricted keyword of sorts. 2) You have *multiple-defined* main, GCC is right. First, you defined it as a void function, and then you again defined it as an int !

Comment: @A P Jo I have changed the name to better address the problem. Again, I have to say there is no such a issue in high level language such as C#, Java, and its weird for me that linker cannot differenciate function and object.

Comment: C# & Java aren't compiled to machine code. They have their VMs/Interpreters. You can do multiple definitions like that there, because a sophisticated environment 'supports' you code to execute it there, and all sorts of trickery can be achieved without you knowing. But when compiled to binary, it runs *on the metal*, where this isn't legal without tricks.

Comment: @APJo — you can have `int foo(void) { int main = 1; printf("%d\n", main++); return ++main; }` using `main` as a local variable.  You can't have a global variable called `main` though.

Comment: The linker works on names — and only names.  The type of the object represented by the name is not material.  You have to different objects called `sth` — you are not allowed to do that (and the linker complains).  Life gets more complex if you have `extern int sth;` in one file and use `sth` as an `int` in that file, and then in another file you have a function `sth`.  However, that's undefined behaviour — nothing is guaranteed except unhappiness.

Answer (score 1):

You gave multiple definitions to the linker.

The symbol `sth` is defined in two modules, one as an `int` and one as a `void` function.  If the same symbol appears in more than one object file, regardless of type, the linker will throw an error if you attempt to link those together.

A symbol can only be defined in one object file.  If you want to use it in others you can *declare* it in the other file(s) however the declaration must match the definition.

Alternately, if you want a particular symbol to only be visible in the file it was defined in and not others, you need to add the `static` storage class specifier to it.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I actually know why it throw an error, but cannot understand why the linker is not designed to  differenciate function and object, as I mentioned in the post, implementation will be a very simple lookup in symtab.

Comment: @amjad In one file you said it was one thing and in the other you said it was something else.  So which one is the linker supposed to pick?  Even if both were defined as the same type you'd *still* get the same error.

Comment: @amjad If you want the symbol in question to be local to just that file and not viewable in others you need to mark it as `static`.

Comment: @amjad: So when you look up a symbol in a dso using dlsym, which of the competing symbols should be returned, in your opinion?