# redefinition error doesn't happen in external source file

Tags: c, gcc, linker

below is my code:

```
//main.c 

int t;
double t = 0;

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

we can see that above code doesn't compile and gcc throw an error:"t redefinition; different basic types", fair enough.

But if I add another soure file to define `t` as:

```
//main.c 

int t;

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

```
//test.c

double t = 0;
```

now the code compiles, but isn't it still same problem here? in main.c, the return type is int while in test.c the return type is doublle, inconsistent type? why it can compile this time?

Comment: This is already answered by [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63663447/1553090).

Comment: Also, variables do not have "return types".  They have "types".  Return types are a feature of _functions_.

Comment: See also [Linker is unable to tell the difference between a function and variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63653212/15168) — also asked by [amjad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9623401/amjad).

Answer (score 2):

That is a problem but it's a *different* problem. The compiler generally works on translation units, which can be simplistically thought of as a single source file plus everything it pulls in with `#include`, and everything *those* included files pull in with `#include`, and so on.

Because `main.c` and `test.c` are separate translation units, they will not interfere with each other as far as the *compiler* is concerned. They *will,* however, almost certainly complain bitterly about double definition of the `t` symbol if you decide to link those compiled translation units together.

Answer (score 2):

> isn't it still same problem here?

Yes and no.  Paragraph 6.2.7/2 of the language specification says:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have
> compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Supposing that in your second example, the two translation units presented are to be evaluated as contributing to one program, then both versions of your code do violate that provision, and therefore they have undefined behavior.  But a C implementation is not required to diagnose that problem, nor to fail in any particular way (or at all) in the face of it.

However, your first example also violates paragraph 6.7/4, whereas your second example does not:

> All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or function shall specify compatible types.

This one is a language constraint, which means that implementations are required to diagnose it (as yours does).  Implementations are *not* required to reject code that fails to conform to this constraint, but the behavior of such code is undefined, and rejecting it is among the better alternatives in the universe of available behaviors.

> in main.c, the return type is int while in test.c the return type is doublle, inconsistent type? why it can compile this time?

The C language specifications do not say, but inasmuch as the behavior of the implementation in translating the program and the behavior of the translated program, if any, are undefined in this case, accepting the code and successfully compiling it to an executable is permitted.  I speculate that your particular implementation just omits `t` from the program altogether, on account of it never being accessed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after reading a textbook, I think it is due to linker, as linker will choose strong variablle against weak variable, thats why it didn't throw an error

Comment: @amjad: neither of those variables is weak (unless you're not showing us an attribute declaration).

Comment: @amjad, it is important to understand that C implementations generally do not diagnose all language violations.  Indeed, one of the key points of undefined behavior is exactly that the program may compile and run despite having UB.  The standard just does not provide any basis for predicting its behavior in that case.  This is the area you are trying to probe.