# What happened if a global variable and a function have the same name?

Tags: c, function, gcc, linker, global-variables

It is known that a function and a variable can't share the same name.
like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This casued by ‘main’ redeclared as different kind of symbol.
But following two files can be compiled successfuly and make me confused.
main.c:

```
void print_main(void);

int main() {
    print_main();
    return 0;
}
```

print_main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char main;

void print_main() {
    printf("Output: 0x%x\n", main);    //Output: ffffffe9
}
```

**Confusion**

- I wonder why compiler didn't remind me ‘main’ redeclared as different kind of symbol?
- why I get a strange number "ffffffe9" and what is it ?
- why the strange number changed when I run these files on another IDE?

**What I've tryed**

- Infact, I have known it's caused by  global variable "main"  and the function "main()" have the same name.
  So,something interesting happened here.
- compile and run this on Visual Studio 2019，the output is "ffffffe9".
  but compile and  run this on CLion, the output will be "0x55"
- When I try to check the address of variable "main" ，I found it is same with the address of function "main()".
  like this

main.c

```
void print_main(void);

int main() {
    printf("%p\n", &main);   // 003D12BC 
    print_main();            
    return 0;
}
```

**print_main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

char main;

void print_main() {
    printf("Output: %x\n", main);   //ffffffe9
    printf("%p\n", &main);          //003D12BC
}
```

Comment: IIRC the C standard doesn't allow it.

Comment: The linker assumes that (global) objects with the same name denote the same object.  You're running into very thin ice, if not fully undefined behaviour.  See C11 [§6.9 External definitions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like I answered substantially the same question a few days ago.  Oh wait, [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63664003/2402272).  I would close the present question as a dupe if the other's OP had accepted an answer.

Summary:

- A conforming compiler must diagnose incompatible declarations of the same identifier in one translation unit, but it is not required to diagnose that issue for declarations in different translation units.
- A conforming compiler is not required to reject the program in either case, whether it emits a diagnostic or not, but if it accepts it then the program has undefined behavior.

> - I wonder why compiler didn't remind me ‘main’ redeclared as different kind of symbol?

It is not obligated to do so (see above), and separate compilation makes it challenging to do so.  Ultimately, this is a quality of implementation issue.

> - why I get a strange number "ffffffe9" and what is it ?

Two words: undefined behavior.

> - why the strange number changed when I run these files on another IDE?

Again: undefined behavior.

It is not much useful to try to dig into the various ways the program's undefined behavior manifests in different C implementations.  Instead, write programs whose behavior is well defined.  Especially do not write programs whose behavior you *know* to be undefined.

Comment: In case the OP accepts the answer here and add the standard quote from your other answer to the duplicate here, then we can close the other question as a dupe to this one.